# Multiple Bindings In WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

Is it possible to have multiple item source bindings in xaml on a wpf control.

Currently I am using mvvm pattern and have an item binding that is bound to one object type.

```
ItemSource="{Binding ProcessModel}"
```

this then has a ItemTemplate

```
ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource PMDataTemplete}"
```

This currently is fine as I was only using one type of object. I want to extend this so I can have one or a 2nd different type of object, but it does not need to be able to bind to both at the same time.

What I am trying to achieve is the situation where one object type can be bound depending on what the user selects and the binding will work and again if the user takes a different route the other type of object is displayed on the same control.

So it is almost the idea of having a case statement based on object types for the itemsource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) (more flexible, but more complex) or define data templates for the types need to be rendered in ItemsControl.

Comment: Thank you that looks like a good solution, I have one question how does that work with the ItemSource in mvvm, in my problem I am bound to a List of a object type but I need two?

Comment: When ItemsControl need to render an item, it determines a type of item and then looks up for data template defined in resources. If the data template cannot be located, control checks for ItemTemplateSelector, and tries to get template from selector. It doesn't mean, which approach you're using - MVVM or not. Also, it doesn't mean, what (and how many) types of objects are in the ItemSource - you can bind to List<Object> and fill list with everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is two options:

1. You can define datatemplates for different types.
2. You can write DataTemplateSelector as Dennis mentioned.